# Does 'ts-loader' require 'typescript' to be installed inorder to work? For me it worked fine

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

The npm documentation for using [`ts-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader) suggests installing `typescript` and so does the official [Typescript guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) in webpack documentation without actually providing any reasoning behind it. For me, the everything is getting build successfully without typescript being installed. What did I miss?

My current setup:

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    // mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin()
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "build:dev": "npm run webpack -- --mode development",
    "start": "npm run webpack serve -- --mode development"
  },
  "author": "ranemihir",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

output:

```
asset bundle.js 1.3 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
asset index.html 233 bytes [compared for emit]
./src/index.ts 111 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 2099 ms
```

Comment: do an `npm list` in your project's folder or inspect your `package-lock.json`. Maybe typescript was installed as a dependency of another package? Or it maybe typescript is installed globally? try `npm list -g` (not sure whether ts-loader can use a globally installed typescript though) Pretty sure you can't compile typescript without a typescript compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in their [`package.json`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/d13d9c3d38d1f68d76d1773937e96df527c11c2a/package.json#L101), `typescript` is marked as a peer dependency.

Prior to npm v7, peer dependencies were not automatically installed, and you would get an error if your package wouldn't depend on TypeScript. Since npm v7, [peer dependencies are automatically installed](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies). Apparently you are using npm version 7 or higher, so TypeScript will be installed.

Nevertheless I would recommend you to add `typescript` to your project's dependencies. `ts-loader` will install always the latest version of TypeScript (note the `"*"`). Whenever TypeScript releases a new version with breaking changes, it would be installed in your project. So if someone opens the projects after some time and runs `npm install`, there is a good chance that the build is broken.

Comment: So, if I were to install a specific version of `typescript`, `ts-loader` will make use of that dependency instead of the version specificed in its peer dependency. Is it true for all modules that you install?

Comment: Yes that's true for all modules. But if you want to install a version of a package which falls outside the peer dependency range for one of your dependencies, npm will throw an error. You can read more about peer dependencies in the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies).